# Assinging df to different pages on streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I have writen the below code to generate a template in streamlit.
I'm struggling to assign a df to each different page.

System 1 will have its own df,
System 2 Will have its own df,
System 3 will have its own df,

Then when they click the radio button it will display a df of all the results for each system.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader('Upload your File Here')

dictionary = {'System 1': ['Selections', 'Results'], 'System 2': ['Selections', 'Results'], 'System 3': ['Selections', 'Results']}

st.title("Choose Your System")

selected_section = st.sidebar.selectbox("Choose Your System:", sorted(dictionary.keys()))
selected_page = st.sidebar.radio("Choose Selection or Results:", sorted(dictionary[selected_section]))

if st.button("Show Todays Selections", "Show Todays Results"):
    st.write(f"Running {selected_section}:{selected_page}")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "each different page"? You want to print 3 dataframes, one for each system, when clicking the same one button?

Comment: Yes, that is the end goal.